# CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9810) Issue (Objc)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ssl, afnetworking, sslhandshakeexception

I have converted an application from ASIHTTPRequest to AFNetworking, all works fine for me, I get response successfully when calling an api, but an issue appears with AFNetworking even set Boolean allowInvalidCertificates to NO.

```
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = NO;
```

I have tried `NSURLConnection` but same issue, all works fine but I get this handshake error log all the time.

Furthermore, I have couple of old applications written in objective c, in which MKNetworking/AFNetworking is being used, APIs are working fine, I am getting response too.

But the thing which bothers me is that I start getting this message in log:

> CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9810)

while calling an API no matter SOAP/REST, weird thing is in few Apps I am not using SSL but still getting it.

I have check through internet/blogs/Stackoverflow and tried all found solutions but problem sustains.

What is this code (-9810) at the end?

Comment: Are you calling https api?

Comment: @NileshPatel yes mostly https but there are few with http

Answer (score 0):

When you set

```
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = NO;
```

at that it will check weather SSL certificate properly installed on Server or not.

If its not installed properly then because of that this error got generated.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the URL of your API?